# Convert string to NDB query

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

If I have a class like:

```
class carModel(ndb.Model):
  type = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  brand = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

I want that a user can type a GQL query into a text field. (Same like at the Datastore viewer).
I'll get the string and insert it into my query - for example:

```
queryString = "carModel.brand=='bmw'"

qry = carModel.query(queryString)

result = query.get()
```

I get following error message:

```
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1059, in filter
raise TypeError('Cannot filter a non-Node argument; received %r' % arg)
TypeError: Cannot filter a non-Node argument; received "carModel.brand=='bmw'"
```

I think that class has not been recognized from the string. Any suggestions for a solution where I can keep the users freedom to use any GQL queries on the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`carModel.brand` is actually a class and property reference not a string.

Either construct the query using GQL, or you have to assemble the query as per the Query class docs which means parsing your own set of arguments.

Be sure to use appropriate substitution rules or someone could query for things not intended and check for GQL that does not comply with what ever rules you have in place, or someone can query for anything.  Remember also that indexes must exist for the queries submitted.

Comment: Thank you!! I ended up using ndb.gql(queryString).